# “Find a number” on a real interval

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on Pugh’s Real Mathematical Analysis, Ch 1.13, which states

Let $b$ be the least upper bound of $S$, where $S$ is a bounded nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

1. Given $\epsilon > 0$. Show that there exists an $s \in S$ with $b - \epsilon \leq s \leq b$.
2. Can $s \in S$ always be found so that $b - \epsilon \leq s \leq b$?

The first problem seems simple. If $b \in S$, then simply let $s = b$: $\;\;b - \epsilon \le b \le b$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. If not, claim no such $s$ exists, then for some $\epsilon > 0$, $b - \epsilon$ is larger than any element of $S$, which makes $b - \epsilon$ an upper bound of $S$. However, since $b$ is already the least upper bound, we get a contradiction.

My problem is that I cannot understand the second question. What does the author mean by “can a number always be found”? Does he mean a constructive proof like the first part of my proof? If so, is there a way to show that $s$ cannot be found?

**UPDATE**: The second question actually says $b - \epsilon < s < b$. Sorry. The answer is trivial in this case, consider a singleton set $S = \{ b \}$.

Comment: Aren't (1) and (2) the exact same sentence, one written as an assignment and the other as a question?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I feel the same : )

Answer (score 1):

You practically answered alreay (2), too!:

"If no such $\;s\;$ exists [for some given $\;\epsilon>0\;$], then $\;b-\epsilon(<b)\;$ is an upper bound for $\;S\;$ ..." contradicting the fact that $\;b\;$ is **the least** such upper bound!

Comment: I made a rather foolish mistake of misreading $\leq$ as $<$. Sorry. : )